# C - Segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am making a Rubik's Cube that can rotate it's rows and columns. My struct is this:

```
typedef struct
{
int **cell;
}face;
```

In this part I am allocating memory for cells. (X is user input)

```
face faceOne; //There are six of this faces
faceOne.cell = (int **)malloc(x * sizeof(int));
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
     faceOne.cell[i] = (int *)malloc(x * sizeof(int));
```

Then I am filling these cells:

```
for (int i = 0; i <  x; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
     {
     faceOne.cell[i][j] = 0;
     printf("%d\n", i);
     }
```

If x is bigger than 3, program crashes with Segmentation fault. How can i solve this?

Comment: `faceOne.cell = malloc(x * sizeof(int));` What if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
faceOne.cell = (int **)malloc(x * sizeof(int));
```

would be

```
faceOne.cell = malloc(x * sizeof(int*));
```

Otherwise you are allocating memory for `x` int variables and then storing `int*` variable on it. In case `sizeof(int) = sizeof(int*)` then it wont be any problem but on the system where this is not the case you have earned yoruself a undefined behavior.

To get rid of all this `**` while using `malloc` the best would be to do this

```
faceOne.cell = malloc(x * sizeof *faceOne.cell);
```

Similarly,

```
faceOne.cell[i] = malloc(x * sizeof *faceOne.cell[i] );
```

And also don't cast the return value of `malloc`. This  suppresses many warning generated by compiler and is unnecessary.

Apart from all this, have you ever wondered what would happen if `malloc` did fail and returned `NULL`? Then you are working on a `NULL` and dereferencing it(Undefined behavior). Check the return value of `malloc`, in case it returns `NULL` handle the error and move on.

Comment: Thanks for explenation, i am still bad at handling memory with pointers and trying to improve this flaw. Can you suggest a source for learning more or practice this subject?

Comment: @MertcanElçi.: Well I can show you a list of good books. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list  Check this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222774/mallocsizeofint-vs-mallocsizeofint-vs-int-mallocsizeofint

Comment: @EsmaeelE.: What you want to say? Casting? Then you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 0):

You want here

```
faceOne.cell = (int **)malloc(x * sizeof(int));
```

to allocate `x` *pointers* to *int*, so this should be

```
faceOne.cell = malloc(x * sizeof(int *));
```

It seems on your system the size of a pointer (to int) is bigger than the size of an int ...

Also in C don't cast *malloc()* ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))